# Flutter - How to create a Bottom sidebar with a persistent Button to open and close it

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I would like to create  bottom sidebar with a persistent button to open and close it , now  use a `showModalBottomSheet` but I don't know how to leave the button attached to the `ModalBottomSheet`

This is what my App do now:
[image]

this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with a `Stack` and `AnimatedPositioned `?

Comment: No..Could you kindly give me a little example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand what you mean, try using this class in a `Stack` and adapt it to what you need:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class CycleSideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CycleSideBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CycleSideBarState createState() => _CycleSideBarState();
}

class _CycleSideBarState extends State<CycleSideBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<CycleSideBar> {
  AnimationController? _animationController;
  StreamController<bool>? isSideBarOpenedStreamController;
  Stream<bool>? isSideBarOpenedStream;
  StreamSink<bool>? isSideBarOpenedSink;
  final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 400);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _animationDuration);
    isSideBarOpenedStreamController = PublishSubject<bool>();
    isSideBarOpenedStream = isSideBarOpenedStreamController!.stream;
    isSideBarOpenedSink = isSideBarOpenedStreamController!.sink;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController!.dispose();
    isSideBarOpenedStreamController!.close();
    isSideBarOpenedSink!.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var heightOfScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    List<Widget> children = [];
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      initialData: false,
      stream: isSideBarOpenedStream,
      builder: (context, isCycleSideBarOpenedAsync) {
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: _animationDuration,
          top: isCycleSideBarOpenedAsync.data!
              ? heightOfScreen - 300
              : heightOfScreen - 113,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => onIconPressed(),
                child: Text('Test'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                  child: Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                    spacing: 10,
                    runSpacing: 10,
                    children: _builItemsOfBottomSheet(children),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void onIconPressed() {
    final animationStatus = _animationController!.status;
    final isAnimationCompleted = animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed;

    if (isAnimationCompleted) {
      isSideBarOpenedSink!.add(false);
      _animationController!.reverse();
    } else {
      isSideBarOpenedSink!.add(true);
      _animationController!.forward();
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _builItemsOfBottomSheet(List<Widget> children) {
    children.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      children.add(Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text('Text_$i')));
    }

    return children;
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I need!!